# mongodb crashes after wiredtiger error - out of space

Tags: mongodb, memory-management, out-of-memory, wiredtiger

```
The following error was found in logs after some consecutive find query.
```

> **2021-03-11T00:04:02.520+0530 E STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread]
> WiredTiger error (28) [1615401242:520448][789:0x7ff0e6251700],
> file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __posix_file_write, 579:
> /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle.set: handle-write: pwrite: failed
> to write 1091 bytes at offset 0: No space left on device Raw:
> [1615401242:520448][789:0x7ff0e6251700], file:WiredTiger.wt,
> WT_SESSION.checkpoint: __posix_file_write, 579:
> /var/lib/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle.set: handle-write: pwrite: failed
> to write 1091 bytes at offset 0: No space left on device**

Instance Configuration

1. Disk Space - 30 Gb
2. Memory - 4 Gb

I still have 15 gb of free space in my machine when i checked using **df -h** command but it throws disk out of
space